# How to pass value from testng.xml to hooks java class

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Passing value from testNG.xml to hooks file gives error When a hook declares an argument it must be of type cucumber.api.Scenario. public void Step_Defination.Hooks.openBrowser(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
[image: hooks.java class] [image: TestNG.xml]

Comment: Please share your code to understand us what have you implemented so far.

Comment: Testng.xml:
<test name="Test">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
      <classes>
      <class name="Test_Runner.testrunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  hooks.java
  @Before
 @Parameters("browser")
 public void openBrowser(String browser) throws IOException  {
   if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","driver//chromedriver.exe");
   driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Cucumber Before hook can only be injected a Scenario object and will not work here. Simplest would be to have a properties file in the classpath with the browser type. Access this file in the before hook

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code. Don't use comments, code is mostly unreadable in comments, and not all comments may be shown initially. Check also [ask].

Comment: Images of code are not searchable, or accessible. When including code in a question please do so using text and formatting that text appropriately either using the format as code button in the editor, or by indenting it with four spaces. If the code can be executed (HTML and JavaScript) including it using a snippet.

Comment: @Grasshopper I want to do cross-browser testing by Property file I have no idea how to achieve it. therefore I was using TestNG.xml to invoke cucumber Page object model framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using TestNG & Cucumber together, we shall not use **@Before (cucumber.api.java.Before)** to read values from testng.xml rather we shall use **@BeforeTest (org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest)** Below is an example of Hooks.java

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

public class Hooks extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUpScenario(String browser){
        //BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser);
    }
}
```

Comment: BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser); Gives error- The method getInstance() is undefined for the type String

Comment: I showed BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser) just for reference. Please use your own method here.